# evaluate Scala abstract syntax tree recursively

Tags: scala, abstract-syntax-tree

Suppose I have  a lambda and I use reify to convert that into an Expr wrapped around a Tree.  For example

```
val expr = reify{x: Int => 3*(4+x)}
```

I can evaluate this for a particular x as follows

```
val toolbox = currentMirror.mkToolBox()
val fun = toolbox.eval(expr.tree).asInstanceOf[Int => Int]
println(fun(10))
```

My goal is to print out the whole tree, annotated with the value at each sub-expression.  How can I determine the  all the sub-expressions and their values?  For example, determine that when x is 10 then there is a subexpression

```
(4+x)
```

that evaluates to 14.  The Traverser class lets me visit each node in the tree, but I cannot figure out how to evaluate the subtrees at each node.

For example, with the following

```
class TestTraverser extends Traverser {
  override def traverse(tree: Tree): Unit = {
    val toolbox = currentMirror.mkToolBox()
    tree match {
      case app @ Apply(fun, args) =>
        val f = toolbox.eval(app.fun)
      case _ =>
    }
    super.traverse(tree)
  }
}
```

calling

```
new TestTraverser().traverse(expr.tree)
```

causes this exception

```
scala.tools.reflect.ToolBoxError: reflective compilation has failed:

ambiguous reference to overloaded definition,
both method * in class Int of type (x: Char)Int
and  method * in class Int of type (x: Byte)Int
match expected type Any
```

Comment: calling eval for sub-trees?

Comment: You would think there would be some way to call eval on the subtree, but I have not found a way to do it.  I have added a Traverser that tries this and does *not* work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved the problem myself. In order to call `toolbox.eval` on a subtree, you need to re-wrap the subtree with information that indicates that it is a function of an `Int` named `x`.  Here is an example of a `Traverser` that works.

```
class WorkingTraverser extends Traverser {
  val toolbox = currentMirror.mkToolBox()
  override def traverse(tree: Tree): Unit = {
    tree match {
      case app @ Apply(fun, args) =>
        val newfun = Function(List(ValDef(Modifiers(PARAM), TermName("x"), Ident(TypeName("Int")), EmptyTree)), Apply(app.fun, app.args))
        val f = toolbox.eval(newfun)
        val f2 = f.asInstanceOf[Int => Int]
        println(app.fun + "(" + app.args + ")" + " evaluates to " + f2(10))
        super.traverse(fun)
        super.traverseTrees(args)
      case _ => super.traverse(tree)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Completely off-topic, but, do you know how is the "@" syntax called? I don't understand how to read it, what it means, where else can I use it, etc.